# Leaving edit mode without any changes still leaves markdown text formatted as code

Tags: jupyter-notebook

First time using Jupyter Notebook, and I'm following online tutorials to try to understand how they work.

One thing I don't understand is why, after double-clicking in a markdown cell and then pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go from Edit Mode to Command Mode, the text is still displayed as if it were code, instead of (formatted) text:

[image]

Clicking outside of the cell doesn't change this either - only by running the cell does it turn back to formatted text. But this happens even when I've not made any changes to the cell's contents, and it seems strange to require that the cell be re-run just to exit edit Mode?!

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer is, simply, that even markdown cells that haven't been edited still need to be (re-)rendered, once one has activated edit mode for them.